# Best way to show a list of empty tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

In a python script I am using an list to store four tuples, and the actual tuples which are stored will change during the script.

Currently, I initialise the list at the top of the script like this:

```
tuples = [(),(),(),()]
```

However, this seems rather ugly.

I then later iteratively assign each index to a generated tuple in a different method:

```
for i in xrange(0, 4):
    tuples[i] = ('a', 'b')
```

The actual values will differ from each other, this is just an example.

---

Alternatively, I could clear the list on each call of the method instead of initialising it as above:

```
tuples = []
```

Then append the four items to it:

```
for i in xrange(0, 4):
    tuples.append('a', 'b')
```

This also seems unintiutive though, since the list will only ever have four values.

What is the best (most pythonic?) way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a place for a list comprehension, much beloved of pythonistas.

Comment: Should each tuple have the same content?

Comment: @jojo *"The actual values will differ from each other, this is just an example"*

Comment: @wnnmaw: In this case the answer by falsetru does not work.

Comment: I edited that in afterwards, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
tuples = [('a', 'b') for _ in xrange(4)]
```

More concisely, using `*` operator:

```
tuples = [('a', 'b')] * 4
```

Recommend the second way only if the elements are immutable ones.

Comment: I should have clarified, the tuples will be different from one another. Is it possible to use a generator in a list comprehension or something similar?

Comment: @iwin, Where does the element to be appended come from?

Comment: @iwin, If the data come from a list of objects, you can still use the list comprehension: `tuples = [(obj.name, obj.value) for obj object_list]`

Comment: Thanks, that works for me; I need to read up on list comprehensions more.